# php via https not working

Tags: nginx, https, php-fpm

I run nginx with php7.4-fpm on a ubuntu 22.04 and I have a info page like this.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

I have this nginx server config.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  root /var/www/html;
  index index.php index.html;
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
  }

}
```

Whenever I call the info.php page via http://example.com/info.php I get php info as expected. No errors!

As soon as I change the server setup to use https://example.com/info.php i get nothing. No output just a blanc page.

This is the https setup

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  ssl_certificate     /etc/......./fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/......./privkey.pem;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

  root /var/www/html;
  index index.php index.html;
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
  }
}
```

BTW, simple html output like `<p>Hello World</p>` works with both configuratons.

Does anyone know why php-fpm does not work with https?

Comment: Have you looked at your php logs? A blank page usually means a critical PHP error which by design does not get shown on the front-end.

Comment: No errors in any log. nginx, php-fpm, syslog

Comment: According to the php-fpm config directives https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php it looks like you have to specifically turn on error logging. If you have not done that see also: https://github.com/rlerdorf/php7dev/issues/48

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason.

I also used this 2 repositories with php7.4, php8.0 and php8.1 installed.

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/nginx
```

What I forgot was to configure php default version which is done by this commands:

```
update-alternatives --config php
update-alternatives --set php-fpm.sock /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock
```

After a reboot everything worked properly.